# Strange background of text in custom theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I recently updated my app, changing it's design a bit. Amongst other things, I styled buttons with custom drawables (well - not exactly custom, just taken from ICS release). Everything works well, except for one of the users.

Instead of:

[image]

He sees:

[image]

This is a Button, but I have also other controls styled with the same background drawable and the problems appears there (so, it's not limited to buttons).

There are two changed style properties that these controls have in common. One is, of course, a background drawable. The other is textAppearance:

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
```

I came to a conclusion, that this user is using some strange theme, which alters the default value of textAppearance* styles. But I have no idea what attribute may control this "text background color" (android:background does not work, checked this just in case). Or maybe I'm looking in the wrong place and this problem is not related to textAppearance?

EDIT:

The background image is a semi-transparent PNG file.
Android version 2.3.7, Motorola Milestone. That's all I got.

EDIT 2, Fixed:

OK, the problem was at the users side, it turned out he was using CyanogenMod7 with forced 16bit trasparency. After switching that option off, everything works.

Comment: If he is the only one, you should provide us more info as the device, android version, etc.

Comment: @DimitrisMakris, I updated the question with all info about user's device that I got. I can't be sure he's the only one, he's currently the only one to report this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was at the users side, it turned out he was using CyanogenMod7 with forced 16bit trasparency. After switching that option off, everything works.